# Copy range between same criteria VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a range between the same string, let’s say I need to copy everything between the two appearances of copy:

```
Copy abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd copy
```

Result:

```
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
```

I’ve searched everywhere and couldn’t find an answer.

I managed to find the last occurrence of the string I want but I can´t figure how to copy the range of rows between the same 2 strings, here´s what I got so far

```
Public Sub buscaIntervalo()
    Dim sPalavra As String
    Dim rngTermo As Range
    sPalavra = "Grupo: 1 - Ativos" 'criteria string

    Set rngTermo = Range("C1:C999").Find(what:=sPalavra, After:=Range("C1"), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
MsgBox (rngTermo.Address) 'returns it´s last occurrence
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You mentioned you've been struggling to write a solution to this problem.  Please edit your question to include the code for those attempts.  This will help others to help you narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, could you offer more explanation?

Comment: If your string is always in the above format (*where the word to be removed is the first and last word*) you can use an excel equation `TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(STRING, "Copy", ""))` where `STRING` is the cell location that has the string.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>I’ve searched everywhere and couldn’t find an answer.</sub>

```
dim str as string, d as string
str = "abc copy ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP QRST UVWX YZ copy def"
d = "copy"
```

Use nested InStr functions to locate the start and stop points.

```
str = mid$(str, instr(1, str, d, vbtextcompare)+len(d)))
str = trim$(left$(str , instr(1, str, d, vbtextcompare) - 1))
debug.print str
```

Use *copy* as the delimiter to split on.

```
str = trim$(split(split(str, d)(1), d)(0))
'*copy* is used for both start and stop; the above could be
str = trim$(split(str, d)(1))
debug.print str
```

Use regular expressions to retrieve the substring.

```
dim rgx as object
set rgx = createobject("vbscript.regexp")
with rgx
    .global = False
    .ignorecase = True
    .multiline = False
    .pattern = d & " (.*?)(?= " & d & ")"
    if .test(str) then
        str = mid$(.execute(str)(0), 6)
        debug.print str
    End If
end with
```

Use worksheet functions to parse the substring.

```
with application.worksheetfunction
    str = .replace(str, 1, .search(d, str) + len(d), vbnullstring)
    str = trim(.replace(str, .search(d, str), len(str), vbnullstring))
    debug.print str
end with

'alternate
with application.worksheetfunction
    str = trim(mid$(.substitute(str, d, space(len(str))), len(str), len(str)))
    debug.print str
end with
```

So it seems you really didn't look that hard after all.

Comment: Hi, Jeeped! The problem is that I need to copy the rows in beetween, it’s a range of rows beetwen the same string appearance. Trust me, I really searched for this.

Comment: application.match returns the first row. appplication.match on an adjusted range fids the second row. copy everything in between. but first, edit your question to accurately reflect what you are attempting. this is why we want to see code attempts. even a failed attempt answers more questions than a narrative.

Comment: i´ve tried this, i figured how to find last occurrence of the string. I can´t figure how to copy the range of rows between the first and last occurrence: `Public Sub buscaIntervalo()
    Dim text As String
    Dim rngTermo As Range
    text = "Grupo: 1 - Ativos"

    Set rngTermo = Range("C1:C999").Find(what:=text, After:=Range("C1"), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
MsgBox (rngTermo.Address)
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a sollution myself, hope it helps someone else.
This code finds the last appearance of the string, gets its address then from that particular cell it copies the chosen range from bottom to top.
Thanks for those who tried to help :)

```
Option Explicit
```

Public Sub buscaIntervaloDinamico()
    Dim sPalavra As String
    Dim rngTermo As Range

```
sPalavra = "Grupo: 1 - Ativos"

Set rngTermo = Range("C1:E999").Find(what:=sPalavra, After:=Range("C1"), _
searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

rngTermo = rngTermo.Address
rngTermo = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(5, -1)).Copy
```

End Sub

Answer (score -3):

This link may help you:
https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=181399

Here, Atomic Shrimp on 16 Oct 2009 wrote:

> Let's say we have a string called strInput containing:
>   123456789#banana#987654
>
> InStr(strInput , "#") returns 10, so we know the position of the first instance of #
>
> InStrRev(strInput , "#") returns 17, so we know the position of the last instance of #
>
> So InStrRev(strInput , "#")-InStr(strInput , "#") gives you (more or less) the length of the bit you want to extract
>
> Mid(strinput, InStr(strinput, "#"), InStrRev(strinput, "#") - InStr(strinput, "#")) returns '#banana' - so we need to start from one position further on:
>
> Mid(strinput, InStr(strinput, "#")+1, InStrRev(strinput, "#") - InStr(strinput, "#")) returns 'banana#' - so we need to make the extracted portion one character shorter:
>
> Mid(strinput, InStr(strinput, "#")+1, InStrRev(strinput, "#") - InStr(strinput, "#")-1) seems to work...
>
> However, if you pass it: 123456789#banana#0000#apple#987654, it will return 'banana#0000#apple' and if you pass it a string with less than two # characters in it, it falls over...